# Cytoscape vs STRING for long list of proteins

Tags: bioinformatics, cytoscape

I am mid-way through my university project, and I have run into an issue. I have a long list of around 1000 proteins that I wanted to analyse in STRING, however, my list is too large. I decided to try and utilise Cytoscape (and downloaded the stringApp), but the networks generated are still very messy. [I've attached a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUIE4.jpg). Is there any way to improve the presentation of the network by downloading any Cytoscape apps or by tweaking the settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is "no".  A slightly longer answer is "it depends".

Showing a hairball really isn't helpful, usually, so you need to refine things somewhat.  What is your data source (i.e. where did the 1000 proteins come from)?  What do you hope to see in the network?  If you are looking for particular groups of proteins (e.g. complexes), you would probably want to use MCL to cluster them first.  If you have some other data you want to map, such as transcriptomic or proteomic data, you could refine your network based on fold change or abundance values.

All that being said, somethings you might try.  First, you are seeing the "fast" version of the network.  Try clicking on the show graphics details button (the diamond in the network view tool bar).  That will give you the full graphics details.  Second, you might try spreading the network out a bit by using the Layout->Layout Tools.  Turn off the "Selected Only" and then adjust the scale.  Finally, depending on your biological question, you might want to eliminate proteins that are only present in the nucleus or cytoplasm, or are only in lung tissue.  This is all possible using the sliders provided by the stringApp's Results Panel.

-- scooter